# How to use a properties file with Hudson in compilation time?

Tags: maven-2, properties, hudson, environment

I have a pom.xml that uses cxf-codegen-plugin to generate a couple of WS clients.

Inside the configuration of cxf-codegen-plugin, there are the WSDL locations.

I would like to externalize those strings to a env.properties file.

I used org.codehaus.mojo's properties-maven-plugin to look inside src/main/resources/conf/app/env.properties.

How can I make Hudson to replace those properties with the apropiate host?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filtering and profiles should work.

Setup a husdon filter file and place in src/main/filters. Create an additional filter file for each region you need to run in.

The filter files should be named similarly, like so: filter-hudson.properties, filter-prod.properties, etc. and contain the same properties:

```
wsdl.host=myHost
etc...
```

Then have simple profiles that contain the environment you run on:

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <id>prod</id>
    <properties>
      <env>prod</env>
    </properties>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <id>hudson</id>
    <properties>
      <env>hudson</env>
    </properties>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

If you then setup your filters in your pom:

```
<filters>
  <filter>src/main/filters/filter-${env}.properties</filter>
</filters>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources/conf/app</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Then the files in conf app will have wsdl.host replaced with the specific values in your filter.

Then when you run your hudson build, add -P hudson to invoke the hudson profile.

There may be a "better" way to do this, but about a year and a half ago, I had success with this technique.  To give proper credit, here's the [blog post](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2006/10/maven2-multi-environment-filter-setup.html) I used as instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to **provide the path to correct WSDL file**. See the following example from [cxf-codgen plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/maven-cxf-codegen-plugin-wsdl-to-java.html).

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${cxf.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-sources</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <sourceRoot>${project.build.directory}/generated/cxf</sourceRoot>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Here the path to the WSDL is modified only by the `basedir`, You can modify that line to:

```
...
<wsdl>${basedir}/${myRelativePath}/myService.wsdl</wsdl>
...
```

The path you can read, as mentioned by you, using the [properties-maven-plugin](http://haroon.sis.utoronto.ca/zarar/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html). The issue is to load the right properties file. This can be done using a profile.

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>fitnesse</id>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-properties-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>initialize</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <files>
                                    <file>etc/config/dev.properties</file>
                                </files>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
<profiles>
```

If all properties only effect the wsdl file, than you can configure the path to the right wsdl file in the profile, which eliminates the need for the properties file.

---

Just in case, that I completely misunderstood you and you only wanted to know, **how to get the properties read from the property file into the wsdl (xml) file,** then have a look at the [maven-config-processor-plugin](http://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/), the syntax for changing xml files is found on the [Transformation Configuration page](http://code.google.com/p/maven-config-processor-plugin/wiki/TransformationConfiguration#XML_File_Processing)

Comment: Yes, you misunderstood what i need. Basically it is similar to what you say, but a little different. Using your example, suppose that the property ${project.build.directory} is ${wsdl.host} and you want to read it from a properties file. I've already done that with properties-maven-plugin. Ok, so now I only need to know How can I make that Hudson replace that property value before running initialize's goal with the correct value.

Comment: Just as a clarification. Everything (properties file, wsdl) is setup and working? Now you just want to modify the properties file, don't you? If that's the case please provide the OS you are intending to use (limits the choices)? It would also be interesting if all parameters in that properties file need to be changed or not.